# Creating event listeners that call the same function and pass a variable

Tags: actionscript-3, function, addeventlistener

I completely messed up my code and did not change the Movieclip names when copying it into StackOverflow, so it made no sense.

I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish the following as3:

```
//THREE EVENT LISTENERS

                shoe_icon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, shoeApp);
                top_icon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, topApp);
                bottom_icon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, bottomApp);

//THREE FUNCTIONS THAT ALL CALL THE SAME FUNCTION BUT PASS A DIFFERENT VALUE
        function shoeApp(event:MouseEvent):void{
            buildSlider("Shoe");
        }
        function topApp(event:MouseEvent):void{
            buildSlider("Top");
        }
        function bottomApp(event:MouseEvent):void{
            buildSlider("Bottom");
        }
//THIS IS MY MAIN FUNCTION WHICH IS ALL BASED ON THE SLIDERTYPE VARIABLE IT RECEIVES 
        function buildSlider(sliderType:String):void{

        }
```

Comment: Please add more details to your app. the code looks strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do here. Because listener all listeners are added to stage wow on MOUSE_DOWN you'll call all 3 functions anyway. At this point you can handle this by single function which will call buildSlider 3 times with different params.

Maybe you want to handle this depends on what you MOUSE_DOWN? In this case you should add listeners to different objects instead of stage.

Comment: You are completely right I did not update my movielcip names on my eventlisteners when I copied my code into SO. Please see my edits above.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't do this?

```
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, addApps);

    function addApps(event:MouseEvent):void{
        buildSlider("Shoe");
        buildSlider("Top");
        buildSlider("Bottom");
    }

//THIS IS MY MAIN FUNCTION WHICH IS ALL BASED ON THE SLIDERTYPE VARIABLE IT RECEIVES 
function buildSlider(sliderType:String):void{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you are trying to create a relationship between a MovieClip and a String value; a `Dictionary` can help you here.

```
private var buttonClipsToActionsMap: Dictionary = new Dictionary();

public function init() : void {
    buttonClipsToActionsMap[buttonShoe] = "Shoe";
    buttonClipsToActionsMap[topApp] = "Top";

    // Bind the Event Listener to the Stage.
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDownEvent);
}

private function onMouseDownEvent(event : MouseEvent) : void {
    // Check to see if the MovieClip clicked is assosated with an Action.
    var action : String = buttonClipsToActionsMap[event.currentTarget];

    // If it does then invoke buildSlider().
    if (action != null) {
        buildSlider(action);
    }
}
```

Notice how you only need a single Event Listener added to the Stage, rather than 3 separate ones on each MovieClip because of [Event Bubbling](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/eventbubbles-eventcancelable-and-eventcurrenttarget).

We are using the Dictionary as a [Map, or HashTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table); a DataStructure which allows a simple 1-1 relationship between two values.

Comment: have you considered that your current target can be something else than a button (maybe the label on the button, or the icon ) ?

Comment: In which case action would be `null` and the if statement underneath would not evaluate to true.

Answer (score -1):

What you should have is

```
//THREE EVENT LISTENERS

buttonShoe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleButtonUp);
buttonTop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleButtonUp);
buttonBottom.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleButtonUp);

//THREE FUNCTIONS THAT ALL CALL THE SAME FUNCTION BUT PASS A DIFFERENT VALUE
function handleButtonUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var argument:String = "";

    switch(event.target)
    {
        case buttonShoe:
        {
            argument = "Shoe";
            break;
        }
        case buttonTop:
        {
            argument = "Top";
            break;
        }
        case buttonBottom:
        {
            argument = "Bottom";
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            trace("something bad happened, we should handle this somehow. but later");
            break;
        }
    }
    buildSlider(argument);       
}

//THIS IS MY MAIN FUNCTION WHICH IS ALL BASED ON THE SLIDERTYPE VARIABLE IT RECEIVES 
function buildSlider(sliderType:String):void
{
   // your code
}
```

Comment: Not convinced by your `handleButtonUp` method; the `default` error case is just going to pass an empty `String` to `buildSlider` - would it not have been better to either [return home early](http://debuggable.com/posts/programming-psychology-return-home-early:4811de9f-ae28-49c2-a7dc-2f154834cda3) or throw a runtime error?

Comment: Yes, JonnyReeves, you are right. This is why I added a nice comment in there. Basically this should never happen but since I do not know the complete context of the app, I cannot say that on default i set string to "Top", "Bottom" or Shoe. If you can tell me that by just looking at the wrong written code in the question then I will defenately vote up all your answers from now on.

Comment: Hi Adrian, no need to get upset :)  The reason for the downvote was because you failed to handle the default 'error' case in the switch statement.  I'm sorry the downvote upset you so much, I can vote it back up if it helps you sleep sounder at night ;)

Comment: It does not upset me at all. I was just wandering what is wring with the text I wrote inside the default: "something bad happened, we should handle this somehow. but later" ?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with the error message, it should just be inside an Error() if you're not going to handle it.